# Rails save file as image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webdav

I use `webdav` protocol. `gem 'net_dav'` it's old but usefull

when i get file through it i receive it like this `\xFF\xD8\xFF\xE0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00H\x00H\x00\x00\xFF\...`

How to convert to real image `.jpg` or `.png`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you will have to decode this base64 string and then save file, something like

```
File.open('file_name.jpg', 'wb') do|f|
  f.write(Base64.decode64(base_64_encoded_string))
end
```